# .NET 2.0 Runtime DLL versions

Tags: .net-framework-version

I recently edited a resource file in VS2008 on a new project (that I've never worked on before -- it was in source control), and noticed that the runtime version changed from *2.0.50727.**5456*** to *2.0.50727.**4971***.

The older, latter version coincides with the version on mscorlib.dll in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` (2.0.50727.4971).

It's clear that my co-workers have a newer version of .NET 2.0 installed. But which one, and which version do I have? I couldn't find any information on DLL versions by product (eg. SP1 vs. non-SP1).

My registry key for `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\v2.0.50727\SP` is set to `0x00000002`, implying I have .NET 2.0 SP2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have the same updates and patches installed. there are a number of updates over the last few years that alter dll version numbers for the framework. 
here's one of them: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2656356

also remember, .net 3.5 uses and provides upgrades to .net 2 facilities to support ASP (3.5 asp uses 2.0 framework for IIS execution but adds some libraries for ajax and additional extensions.)